# knockout js: initializing value of dropdown that is nested in an observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

I have seen some solutions elsewhere for this problem, but have not yet found how to make this work in my *specific circumstances*.

An observableArray populates an html list. Inside the list, a user can edit one of the values for a particular row. The item to be edited in the row is itself an observableArray that populates a dropdown list. The array for the drop down list is populated via an ajax call when an edit button on the row is clicked (edit button not shown in code below).

I have this all working fine, except for one important issue: as of yet, the value in the dropdown list is not being pre-populated.

Below is a gross mockup of what the real code is doing.

If I call `selectedTeamType` as `selectedTeamType()` in the html, then the intial value **is** populated, but further changes to the select box are not registered. If I call `selectedTeamType` as just `selectedTeamType`, then the intial value is not set properly, but further changes to the select box **are** registered.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>    <!-- ko foreach: my.TeamViewModel.Teams -->
      <td data-bind="text: TeamID"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: TeamText"></td>
      <td>  <!-- the TeamType will be editable, so we provide a dropdown list, but default to the current value -->
         <select data-bind="options: my.TeamViewModel.TeamTypes, 
             optionsText: 'TeamTypeText', 
             optionsValue: 'TeamTypeID', 
                 value: selectedTeamType"></select>
        </td>
   </tr> <!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var my = my || {};

$(function () {

my.TeamModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.TeamID = ko.observable();
         self.TeamText = ko.observable();
    self.TeamTypeID = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTeam = ko.observable(); 
         self.Edit = function () {
            my.TeamViewModel.load_TeamTypes();
        };
};

my.TeamTypesModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.TeamTypeID = ko.observable();
    self.TeamTypeText = ko.observable();
};

my.TeamViewModel = function () {
    var Teams = ko.observableArray([]),
        TeamTypes = ko.observableArray([]),
        load_TeamTypes = function () {
            $.ajax({
                      // only part of ajax call displayed here for sake of brevity...              
                                $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                                    TeamTypes.push(new my.TeamTypesModel()
                                            .TeamTypeID(d.TeamTypeID)
                                            .TeamTypeText(d.TeamTypeText)
                                    );
                                });
            });
        },
        load_Teams = function () {
            $.ajax({
                      // only part of ajax call displayed here for sake of brevity...   
                    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                        Teams.push(new my.TeamModel()
                                .TeamID(d.TeamID)
                                .TeamText(d.TeamText)
                        );
                    });
                }
            });
        };
    return {
        Teams: Teams,
        TeamTypes: TeamTypes,
        load_TeamTypes: load_TeamTypes
    };
} ();

my.TeamViewModel.load_Teams();
ko.applyBindings(my.TeamViewModel);
```

});

Comment: I think selectedTeam() should work. So if you use selectedTeam() with parens, then change the drop down value and check the observable's value via javascript debugger it doesn't change? If put together a JSFiddle for debugging but it's my bedtime :-(

Comment: I believe the last paragraph of my question explained how that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Is `selectedTeamType` set before the `my.TeamViewModel.TeamTypes` array is populated? If so, this could be why its initial value is not being set. I don't see anywhere in the javascript you posted where you are setting the initial value of `selectedTeamType`.

**Update**

Your answer to your own question confirmed my suspicion above. Is there a reason why you need to load the team types dropdown every time a user goes to edit a team? If the select options are the same for every team, why not just load it once?

Example:

```
my.TeamViewModel.load_Teams();
my.TeamViewModel.load_TeamTypes();
ko.applyBindings(my.TeamViewModel);
```

This way, the options list should already be loaded by the time a user clicks the edit button. It could save your client/server some sweat too, if a fresh team types options list is not needed for every team in the list.

If you want to guarantee that both `$.ajax` calls will complete before you do anything, I suggest looking into jQuery's `$.Deferred` method and promise API. When you have more than 1 `$.ajax` call, and you need to perform an action only after both have succeeded, you can do something like this:

```
var defer_Teams = $.Deferred();
var defer_TeamTypes = $.Deferred();
$.ajax({ // initiate the server call to get teams
    url: '/teams',
    success: function(data) {
        defer_Teams.resolve(data); // tell the promise API this is ready
    }
});
$.ajax({ // initiate the server call to get team types
    url: '/team-types',
    success: function(data) {
        defer_TeamTypes.resolve(data); // tell the promise API this is ready
    }
});

$.when(defer_Teams, defer_TeamTypes).then(function(teamData, teamTypeData) {

    $.each(teamTypeData, function(i, d) {
        // populate team types array
        // could also do this with ko.mapping instead of $.each
    })

    $.each(teamData, function(i, d) {
        // populate teams array
        // could also do this with ko.mapping instead of $.each
    })

});
```

Say your /teams call returns fast, but your /team-types call lags. With the above, the teams array would not be populated until both calls finish. And you really do need that types call to finish before the user can click the edit button and get the selected value pre-populated.

Answer (score 1):

The apparent fix involved two steps:

First, pass a reference to the current item and its current `TeamType` in the `Edit` function.

```js
self.Edit = function () {
    var that = this; 
    var _TeamType = self.TeamTypeID();
    my.TeamViewModel.load_TeamTypes(that, _TeamType);
};
```

Then, and most importantly, pass those references to the function that loads the TeamTypes, 
and **set the selectedTeamType AFTER the TeamTypes array has loaded; in this case, the selectedTeamType is set in the `complete` function of jQuery's `ajax`.

```js
load_TeamTypes = function (that, _TeamType) {
    $.ajax({
              // only part of ajax call displayed here for sake of brevity...              
                        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                            TeamTypes.push(new my.TeamTypesModel()
                                    .TeamTypeID(d.TeamTypeID)
                                    .TeamTypeText(d.TeamTypeText)
                            );
                        });

                //...ajax continued
                complete: function () {
                    that.selectedTeamType(_TeamType);
                }
    });
},
```

Comment: This makes sense. If you set the selected value to an option not in the drop down, it's ignored. So I bet you were setting it, it was getting ignored because it didn't match any available option, and then when options changed, it didn't update the selected value.

Comment: What happens if the `load_Teams` ajax call finishes before the `load_TeamTypes` ajax call? Have you tried setting a delay in the `load_TeamTypes` server call to test this?

Comment: @danludwig - not sure I follow... The only way the `load_TeamTypes` can be called is if the Teams list is displayed and the button that calls the Edit function for an item in the Teams list is visible. So I can't ever see a situation where the `load_TeamTypes` would be called prior to `load_Teams`.

Comment: @mg1075 ok gotcha. You are right that you have to set the `<select>` element's `value` binding (`selectedTeamType`) *after* the `options` array is populated. If you try to do it before, knockout will not see the `<option>` in the dropdown, and it does not cache to set it after the `options` array gets populated. Still looks funny to set `selectedTeamType` during `complete` though. Do you still need to set it even if the ajax call fails? Can't you just `that.selectedTeamType(_TeamType);` after the `$each` loop completes? Also, shouldn't the Edit function call `my.TeamViewModel.load_TeamsTypes`?

Comment: @danludwig - yep, it also worked after the `$each`, and did not work if just before the `$each`. My thinking with the `complete` was that by setting the selected value there, it would be *guaranteed* to run after the `$each` populates the dropdown list. Also, yes, the call for `Edit` should be to `load_TeamTypes`. Sorry for the mix-up there; it's twice the work when trying to make a real case to be anonymous.

Comment: @mg1075 that's true, and it will also be guaranteed to run if the ajax call fails. But `$.each` is not async, so anything you put after it should also be guaranteed to run after the `$each` populates. Is there a reason why you are loading the options each time a user edits a team? Does the options list depend on which team you are editing, or is it the same for all teams?

Comment: @danludwig - No, the options list is the same for all teams and unlikely to be altered elsewhere by others in the course of editing a particular team.

Comment: @danludwig - which leads to the next question, why not just call `my.TeamViewModel.load_TeamTypes();` at initialization and bypass all the workarounds? Indeed, that approach probably makes the most sense.

Comment: @mg1075 yes, I updated my answer with that suggestion. I still think you should use `$.Deferred` though, it is a great solution to this very problem of binding select options and values using knockout when both the options and other edit data come from `$.ajax` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your constructor to take in d like so

```
my.TeamTypesModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.TeamTypeID = ko.observable(data.TeamTypeId);
        self.TeamTypeText = ko.observable(data.TeamTypeText);
    };
```